# How to Remove elementary desktop environment?

Tags: 12.10, uninstall, ppa, purge, elementary

I'm running ubuntu 12.10 and yesterday I installed elementary from `ppa:elementary-os/daily`. I later realized that elementary replaces the stock nautilus with another version that looks misplaced in Unity which is my main environment.

Any one know how to remove all elementary related packages? 
I tried with `ppa-purge` which didn't work, so I tried to purge elementary* that still left most of the packages I think, at least the dock (plank) and the desktop Environment (Pantheon).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's a way to remove all packages installed through a ppa and restore the original ones.

1. `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`
2. `sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily`

   If daily was installed

   or

`sudo ppa-purge ppa:/elementary-os/stable`

If elementary os stable was installed.

That's it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip but as i wrote in the question i have tried that and it didn't help

Comment: I re-enabled the ppa then I used ppa-purge again and this time it worked, dont know what happend the last time, I got no errors.

Comment: Works, thanks a lot. But it still shows elementary os in the about dialog of ubuntu 20.04. Is this just a config issue somewhere ?

Comment: That would be suitable for another question on AskUbuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Install Synaptic Package Manager: `sudo apt-get install synaptic`
Type `synaptic` to launch it.
Search for  `elementary` and select complete removal on the check box.
Apply the changes.
Done!

Answer (score 1):

Open a Terminal window:

- Type `software-properties-gtk` then press Enter
- Locate the elementary PPA uncheck the box and then click on Remove, enter your
  password, close the window.

[image]

- Then run `sudo apt-get update` in the Terminal window.

If you don't remember which packages you picked from the PPA use Synaptic.

In the Terminal window type `gksu synaptic` enter your password and once the Synaptic window open search for "elementary", then sort the packages so that the installed ones show up at the top, then uninstall them.

Comment: Pardon me if I'm mistaken, but isn't this exactly what ppa-purge does? I have already removed the ppa but the environment remains.

Comment: No, PPA purge does 2 things, first it removes the PPA from your sources, then if any packages were upgraded via the PPA they're downgraded to Ubuntu stock versions. Since the elementary PPA doesn't upgrade anything in Ubuntu it only removed the PPA. However you can use Synaptic to remove what's been left over.

Comment: Uri Herrera,    Thanks so much for suggesting Synaptic. It got rid of all the Elementary and Pantheon stragglers for me!