# How to completely remove Elementary-Desktop from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, elementary-theme

I installed Elementary OS Desktop on Ubuntu 14.04, and after that I removed it, but it's not completely removed.

I have changes in Unity, for example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Change the theme.

Comment: How to change theme ?

Comment: Install `unity-tweak-tool` with `sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`, then run the application and change the theme.

Comment: No, this is not a solution for me!

Comment: Because it does not work?

Comment: 'unity-tweak-tool' is installed and change theme, but my Unity not back.!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity showing wrong distribution name](https://askubuntu.com/q/817589/61218)

Answer (score -1):

**Reset Unity:**

`unity --reset`

Or you can try to

**Reset Theme:**

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme ''
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences theme ''
```

Comment: --reset deprecated and it is reset, your answer no solution for me!

Comment: Exclamation! How did you install Elementary OS Desktop?

Comment: I did install from http://askubuntu.com/questions/630914/problem-after-install-elementary-os-desktop-in-ubuntu-14-04 , use from answer command for install

Comment: Run `software-properties-gtk` in Terminal, then make sure the theme's ppa's are all checked/enabled. Then do the following: 1) `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge` 2) `sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily`

Comment: Which ppa ? I remove all elementary os ppa and remove elementary desktop! (Then do the following: ) what do you mean ?

Comment: [Run "gksu synaptic" in a Terminal, and enter your password. Once the Synaptic window opens, search for "elementary", then sort the packages so that the installed ones show up at the top, then uninstall them.](http://askubuntu.com/a/229112/415700)

Comment: I did it all ! :-(

Comment: Try `setsid unity` to reset Unity.

Comment: No solution .!.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24358/discussion-between-synergist-and-digicom).

Comment: I have 10 reputation.! and no chat for me!

Comment: Okay, good luck .!.

Comment: elementry-desktop is a meta package - add the ppa back and use ppa-purge

Answer (score -1):

Test this:

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the `Grub menu`.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `recovery mode`

Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.

Select In this order: `Network`  -- `Drop to root shell prompt`.

In the terminal run:

```
mount -o remount, rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(elementary),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
reboot
```

## [Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/aptitude.8.html)

Comment: Thanks, But I now re-installed Ubuntu. Oops.!