# How to delete all Desktop UI

Tags: 14.04, unity, desktop-environments

I install Elementary-Desktop on Ubuntu 14.04, after install and work with that, I don't like Elementary-Desktop and Delete that but Unity to Demolished.
I try for built Unity (reset, reinstall) but No effect!
Now, how to Delete all Desktop UI and reinstall Unity ?

This is my Unity:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to completely remove Elementary-Desktop from Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/631023/how-to-completely-remove-elementary-desktop-from-ubuntu-14-04)

Comment: No, it is Delete of Elementary.!

Comment: Don't post duplicate questions, even if you get no answer. Delete of Elementary is the same as delete all and reinstall unity.

Comment: You are speaking about question and no help me!

Comment: Duplicate, see Synergist comment.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

Switch on your computer.

Press and hold the Shift key, which will bring up the `Grub menu`.

Select the line which starts with `Advanced options`.

Select the line ending with `recovery mode`

Your PC should display a menu with a number of options.

Select In this order: `Network`  -- `Drop to root shell prompt`.

In the terminal run:

```
mount -o remount, rw /
mount --all
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall aptitude deborphan ppa-purge
aptitude remove '?and(?reverse-depends(elementary),?not(?reverse-depends(?exact-name(ubuntu-desktop))))'
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get dist-upgrade
deborphan
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan)
deborphan --libdevel
apt-get --purge remove $(deborphan --libdevel)
deborphan --find-config
dpkg --purge $(deborphan --find-config)
apt-get autoremove
apt-get clean
ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily
reboot
```

## [Source](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/aptitude.8.html)