# Unity shows wrong distribution name

Tags: unity, desktop-environments, elementary-theme

Recently I had installed Pantheon (Elementary OS desktop environment). I didn't like it, so I uninstalled it, but **Elementary OS Desktop** still appear in the title bar. And in the shutdown button menu, **Ubuntu Help** is replaced by **Elementary OS Help**.

[image: Elementary OS message in Ubuntu desktop]

I want that it says **Ubuntu Desktop** and **Ubuntu Help**. How do I fix it?

The output of `lsb_release -a` is:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description:    elementary OS 0.4 Loki
Release:        0.4
Codename:       loki
```

For installation, I use:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily 
sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get dist-upgrade sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop
```

For uninstallation, I remove each repository manually, then `sudo apt-get autoremove`. And the rest with *Synaptic Package Manager*.

Comment: No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: elementary
Description: elementary OS 0.4 Loki
Release: 0.4
Codename: loki

Comment: How did you install and uninstalled it?

Comment: I've given an answer to your question. You can check it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The PPAs you used to install elementary not only provided elementary specific packages, but also *patched* many standard Ubuntu packages and with your `apt-get dist-upgrade` command they all get installed and mixed into your system. Which means some of the core packages are not from Ubuntu repository, but from those elementary PPAs.

For example, This ppa https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/os-patches provides many packages that are also available in Ubuntu repository. Since the PPA provides those package with higher version (and patched of course), those are preferred by `apt` and get installed into your system while you did the `dist-upgrade` command.

---

For your specific problem, I identified the package which is responsible for showing the distribution name on top-left corner of Unity Panel. It is called `base-files`. I tested the elementary PPA by installing it and not surprisingly I too got those elementary marks :D.

But to solve this, you just can't remove it, because this is an essential package and Ubuntu needs it. What you need to do is re-installing from Ubuntu repository. Use this command to do so.

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install base-files/xenial-updates
```

This command will install the package from Ubuntu's `xenial-updates` archive. After a logout and login, you'll see the changes reverted back.

---

To completely remove Elementary effect from your system, you should go back to Ubuntu versions for all packages. To do so, use `ppa-purge` (and not `apt-add-repository --remove` command, which will just remove the repository entry). For example,

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/daily 
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/testing 
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
```

`ppa-purge` will remove packages from these PPAs and install the ones from Ubuntu archives.

**Note:** If you already removed the Elementary PPA entries (by deleting the lines from `sources.list` files) add them again and then use `ppa-purge`.

Answer (score 1):

To change the information related to your distribution release and codename, edit the file `/etc/lsb-release`:

```
gksu gedit /etc/lsb-release
```

Mine contains the following information:

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS"
```

Comment: if i put  `lsb_release -a` everything is correct. But the initial problem (title at title bar) there is still.

Comment: @GabrielSandoval did you already reboot?

Comment: yes, i was. please help me

Comment: @GabrielSandoval as asked in another comment by Anwar, please include the way you installed Pantheon.

Comment: For install i use the next code `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/daily
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

sudo apt-get install elementary-theme elementary-icon-theme elementary-default-settings elementary-desktop`  For unistall i remove each repository manually, then `sudo apt-get autoremove`. And the rest with Synaptic Package Manager.

Comment: @GabrielSandoval add the information in the question please.