# Ubuntu changed to elementary os?

Tags: grub2, updates

I've installed updates and noticed that my Ubuntu 16.04 changed it's recognition to elementary OS. There is elementary everywhere, in grub (no more Ubuntu) In the settings menu:

[image: right corner click]

I mean, it's not a huge issue, by I love Ubuntu and would not like to see it anywhere

Comment: Did you install or configure any Elementary OS repositories on your system?  You might've tried adding an eOS repo to your system to gain access to something, and it overwrote what was there in Ubuntu.  (In essence, you're technically on eOS if this is what you did, and you might have 'reinstall' to return to Ubuntu specifically, depending on exactly what had changed on the system...)

Comment: nope, simple apt-get update and upgrade

Comment: Include the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list` as an edit to your question.

Comment: but it looks like I've found my answer here https://askubuntu.com/questions/817589/unity-shows-wrong-distribution-name sorry for the dublicate

Comment: to make it fast to find, this fixes the issue `sudo apt-get --reinstall install base-files/xenial-updates`

Comment: @Artemio If you found a solution, please make it a proper answer.  Comments are not persistent and besides this site is QA ( question/answer) format, not forum. Cheers !

Comment: If the related post gave you exact answer, i.e. exactly the solution, then this question can be considered a duplicate and subject to voting

Answer (score 1):

Fast fix for ubuntu 16

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install base-files/xenial-updates
```

After reboot this has fixed all my issues