# Ubuntu OS name changed to Elementary OS

Tags: kubuntu, ubuntu-mate, plymouth, elementary

I have been using Ubuntu MATE 20.04 with Kubuntu desktop environment installed on top. I installed Elementary desktop just to get a feel of it, i didn't like and then I tried to remove the PPAs and get back to ther kde desktop environment.

Still grub is changed, the Plymouth screen is gone and instead boot text is showing, kde theming is affected.
But i could reverse these by removing elementary packages from Synaptic package manager except for the boot text.

Now there aren't any [PPAs](https://askubuntu.com/a/1085156/1186073) of Elementary, but still the OS name has changed. I think some of the base files of Ubuntu have been overwritten.

Results of `sudo apt --reinstall install base-files/xenial-updates` :

```
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree       
 Reading state information... Done
 E: Release 'xenial-updates' for 'base-files' was not found
```

Results of `lsb_release -a` :

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Elementary
Description:    elementary OS 6 Early Access
Release:        6
Codename:       odin
```

Results of `dpkg -l | grep -i elementary` :

```
ii  base-files                                    11ubuntu5.3+elementary11~ubuntu20.04.1            amd64        Debian base system miscellaneous files
ii  libmalcontent-0-0:amd64                       0.10.0-1+elementary3~ubuntu6.1                    amd64        library for parental control of applications
ii  libplymouth5:amd64                            0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2+elementary2~ubuntu6.1 amd64        graphical boot animation and logger - shared libraries
ii  libreoffice-style-elementary                  1:6.4.6-0ubuntu0.20.04.1                          all          office productivity suite -- Elementary symbol style
ii  lsb-base                                      11.1.0ubuntu2+elementary2~ubuntu6.0.1             all          Linux Standard Base init script functionality
ii  lsb-release                                   11.1.0ubuntu2+elementary2~ubuntu6.0.1             all          Linux Standard Base version reporting utility
ii  plymouth                                      0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2+elementary2~ubuntu6.1 amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer
ii  plymouth-label                                0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2+elementary2~ubuntu6.1 amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - label control
ii  plymouth-theme-elementary                     5.9.0+r16~daily~ubuntu6.1                         all          graphical boot animation and logger
ii  plymouth-theme-spinner                        0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2+elementary2~ubuntu6.1 amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - spinner theme
ii  plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text                    0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.2+elementary2~ubuntu6.1 amd64        boot animation, logger and I/O multiplexer - ubuntu text theme
```

kde system info shows *Kubuntu 6*, but neofetch shows:

```
OS: elementary OS 6 Early Access x86_64                                                            
Host: B550M G10a 
Kernel: 5.11.0-051100-generic 
Uptime: 16 mins 
Packages: 3744 (dpkg), 23 (flatpak), 16 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.8 
Resolution: 1366x768 
DE: Plasma 
WM: KWin 
WM Theme: Lightly 
Theme: Adapta [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Fluent-green-dark [Plasma], Fluent-green-dark [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
Terminal Font: Monospace 9 
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 PRO 4650G with Radeon Graphics (12) @ 3.700GHz 
GPU: AMD ATI 0e:00.0 Renoir 
Memory: 2141MiB / 15450MiB
```

Results of `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` :

```
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only 
available from the latest supported release.
```

Is there any way to rename the operating system back to Ubuntu and get the Plymouth screen back? More importantly can I update to Ubuntu 21.04 when the upgrade is released?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/817589/unity-shows-wrong-distribution-name

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to wipe your system and start with a clean installation. Installing packages here and there will leave a lot of cruft afterwards ... wrong release names being just one of them.